# Merge nc files with different longitude and latitude but same timestamps

Tags: ubuntu, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have downloaded some ERA5 data for eastern North America at noon (12:00). This means I had to download nc-files separately to match 12:00 noon for different longitudes. Hence, between longitude -52.5 and -67.5, the timestamp is 16.00, while it is 17.00 for between -67.5 and 82.5. They however all go from 2000 to 2020, a total of 7671 timestamps. On top of that, the nc-files also differ in latitudes.

```
data a:
Dimensions:    (latitude: 177, longitude: 61, time: 7671)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -67.5 -67.25 -67.0 ... -53.0 -52.75 -52.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 90.0 89.75 89.5 89.25 ... 46.5 46.25 46.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01T16:00:00 ... 2020-12-31T16:00:00
Data variables:
    t2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...

data b:
Dimensions:    (latitude: 185, longitude: 61, time: 7671)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -82.5 -82.25 -82.0 ... -68.0 -67.75 -67.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 90.0 89.75 89.5 89.25 ... 44.5 44.25 44.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01T17:00:00 ... 2020-12-31T17:00:00
Data variables:
    t2m        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
```

I tried to use `cdo cat` and `cdo mergetime`, but I get different errors.

```
cdo cat temp*.nc out_temp.nc

cdo    cat:  12%
Warning: Grid size of the input parameter t2m do not match!
```

and

```
cdo mergetime temp*.nc out_temp.nc
Warning: Grid size of the input parameter t2m do not match!
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

The cdo operator collgrid is designed for collecting horizontal grids into one. Try this:

```
cdo collgrid temp*.nc out_temp.nc
```

This should work so long as you have a complete grid to merge.

Comment: I get the following message: `ysize=137 differ from first file (ysize=145)!`

Comment: They need to be equally sized rectangles for collgrid to work. Your answer suggests the latitudes vary

Comment: Yes, so collgrid does not work with files with various latitude ranges?

Comment: Yes, it requires the grids to be collected to form a structured grid. You might be able to solve the problem using `mergegrid`.

Comment: Hi all. I have tried to edit the question as I understand why it was unclear. Unfortunately, the `collgrid` and `mergegrid` did not work. Any other solution to basically join the NC files?

Comment: CDO is probably unsuited for this. Python would using pandas and xarray. Read everything into a pandas dataframe, merge them, then convert to xarray, then netcdf. Otherwise, you are trying to get CDO to do something it wasn't designed to do